# How to speed up this calculation

Tags: c#, performance

Given two ARGB colors represented as integers, 8 bit/channel (alpha, red, green, blue), I need to compute a value that represents a sort of distance (also integer) between them.

So the formula for the distance is: `Delta=|R1-R2|+|G1-G2|+|B1-B2|` where Rx, Gx and Bx are the values of the channles of color 1 and 2. Alpha channel is always ignored.

I need to speed up this calculation because is done a lot of times on a slow machine. What is the 'geekies' way to calculate this on a single thread given the two integers.

My best so far is but I guess this can be improved further:

```
    //Used for color conversion from/to int
    private const int ChannelMask = 0xFF;
    private const int GreenShift = 8;
    private const int RedShift = 16;

    public int ComputeColorDelta(int color1, int color2)
    {
        int rDelta = Math.Abs(((color1 >> RedShift) & ChannelMask) - ((color2 >> RedShift) & ChannelMask));
        int gDelta = Math.Abs(((color1 >> GreenShift) & ChannelMask) - ((color2 >> GreenShift) & ChannelMask));
        int bDelta = Math.Abs((color1 & ChannelMask) - (color2 & ChannelMask));

        return rDelta + gDelta + bDelta;
    }
```

Comment: First 2 questions: Are you sure this is your bottleneck ? Did you establish that through profiling ?

Comment: I don't see much wrong with this. It seems unlikely to be the bottleneck.

Comment: Have you profiled to confirm that this is the bottleneck? Have you done performance testing to determine if the current performance is insufficient?

Comment: Are you able to easily convert the two images into byte arrays instead of integer arrays before you begin?  This would make the calculation simpler because you only have to find the difference between byte values without any shifting.

Comment: Oh if only there were an easy way to access SIMD from .Net :)

Comment: Seriously, though, I agree with the previous comments - there's not really anything wrong with this.  If you are working over a pair of bitmaps, then you might consider passing in the arrays and baking the calculation into the same method; although that said the JIT is likely to inline.  Profiling would be a good idea.

Comment: What could be wrong with sums, subtractions, shifts and `& masks`? Had it been Pythagorean Theorem distance at least... I was writing the speed up for that and then I saw your real problem :-(

Answer (score 3):

Long Answer:

How many is "a lot"

I have a fast machine I guess, but I wrote this little script:

```
 public static void Main() {
            var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                int compute = ComputeColorDelta(r.Next(255), r.Next(255));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And the output is: 
6878

So 7 seconds for 100 million times seems pretty good.

We can *definitely* speed this up though. I changed your function to look like this:

```
public static int ComputeColorDelta(int color1, int color2) {
  return 1;
}
```

With that change, the output was: 5546. So, we managed to get a 1 second performance gain over 100 million iterations by returning a constant. ;)

Short answer: this function is not your bottleneck. :)

Comment: i think the Random will take most of the time, how is runtime if you just pass `i` into `ComputeColorDelta` and then compare?

Comment: @aquinas Change your code to generate all the Random numbers into a list first and rather use new StopWatch() default constructor, calling .Start() and .Stop() independently? I think your first measurement is measuring the cost of r.Next() twice as well...

Comment: hhehehe. I was really just trying to make a point here, I wasn't claiming this was the best benchmark ever :)

Comment: Its a good point. But I get 1237 and 40 respectively. Definitely worth optimising that code if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to let runtime to make calculation for me.

First of all I define struct with explicit field offset

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Color
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public int Raw;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte Blue;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public byte Green;
    [FieldOffset(16)] public byte Red;
    [FieldOffset(24)] public byte Alpha;
}
```

the calculation function will be:

```
public int ComputeColorDeltaOptimized(Color color1, Color color2)
{
    int rDelta = Math.Abs(color1.Red - color2.Red);
    int gDelta = Math.Abs(color1.Green - color2.Green);
    int bDelta = Math.Abs(color1.Blue - color2.Blue);

    return rDelta + gDelta + bDelta;
}
```

And the usage

```
public void FactMethodName2()
{
    var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var color1 = new Color(); // This is a structs, so I can define they out of loop and gain some performance
    var color2 = new Color(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        color1.Raw = i;
        color2.Raw = 100000000 - i;
        int compute = ComputeColorDeltaOptimized(color1, color2);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds); //5393 vs 7472 of original 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: change Black to Blue, but +1 anyway for showing me the FieldOffset, I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use the same code you already have, but in a different order: apply the mask, take the difference, then shift.

Another modification that might help is to inline this function: that is, instead of calling it for each pair of colors, just compute the difference directly, inside whatever loop executes this code. I assume it is inside a tight loop, because otherwise its cost would be negligible.

Lastly, since you're probably getting image pixel data, you'd save a lot by going the `unsafe` route: make your bitmaps like this [EditableBitmap](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/fastimagedrawing.aspx), then grab the byte* and read the image data out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in order to reduce the AND operations:

```
public int ComputeColorDelta(int color1, int color2)
{
    int rDelta = Math.Abs((((color1  >> RedShift) - (color2  >> RedShift))) & ChannelMask)));
    // same for other color channels

    return rDelta + gDelta + bDelta;
}
```

not much but something...

Comment: I'm not convinced this is correct: the channels will interfere with each other. Consider "0x00FF00 - 0x0000FF": your formula gives "0xFE" for the green channel difference. You have to apply the mask to each color first.

Comment: No, your formula takes the difference first, then shifts. The difference is `0x00FE01`, shifted `0x00FE`, masked `0xFE`.

Comment: Thanks :) For the record, I don't downvote if I posted an answer of my own, so it wasn't me :)